# Trying to deploy a react app but it isn't working out to me why?

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment

I am having  issue deploying my react app using render , for reference I am using node, I didn't have a  negative feedback in my render in particular in the log it just kept loading

I tried npm run build which created a static file called dst then I installed npm -g serve right and pushed the app to github and via github connected my code to render, my issue is that it keeps loading and never complete the log repeats the same info over and over

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.